# How to create 3D linear algebra visualizations with javascript or python?

Tags: javascript, python, data-visualization, visualization

Which programming language and libraries would you recommend me to recreate the 3D geometric and linear algebra visualizations displayed in this book http://immersivemath.com/ila/learnmore.html ? I speculate it's either JavaScript or Python, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

The most used JS library for 3D visualizations is [Three](https://threejs.org/). It's not the simplest to learn but the docs are great, it's powerful, and its popularity makes it "community-validated".

Another choice would be [Babylon](https://www.babylonjs.com/), which also have great documentation and also relies on WebGL for rendering.

[D3](https://d3js.org/), the de-facto standard for custom JS visualizations in JS, also handles a bit of 3D, although it's not focused on that.

If library size is a factor you consider, then [Light](https://github.com/evanw/lightgl.js) might be a better choice, and if zero-dependency is also a plus, then you might consider [Seen](http://seenjs.io/).

[Cannon](http://www.cannonjs.org/) is more a 3D physics engine than a 3D visualization library, but it might come handy sometimes.

Consider also [CopperLicht](https://www.ambiera.com/copperlicht/), [Phoria](http://www.kevs3d.co.uk/dev/phoria/), and [Scene](http://scenejs.org/).

---

I wouldn't recommend doing 3D visualizations on the browser in Python, since there are many libraries in JS that are quite powerful, and moving a computationally expensive task such as 3D rendering on the server might overload it, not to mention the lack of interactivity that server-side rendering might incur.